# Can I connect my ipod's earphones to my computer?

Tags: audio, headphones

My computer (recent model Dell z600) has 2 input devices on the front of the computer, 1 has an icon of headphones and the other is a Mic icon.

When I plugin my earphones to the input device that has the headphones, and play some sound I don't hear anything from my earphones (sounds comes from built in speakers).

I know when I plugin a USB headphone set, it switches over to those on but for some reason my earphones are not being picked up.

Is it not compatible?

Note: my earphones look similar to http://www.hdaccessory.com/catalog/reprearphone.jpg

[image]

Comment: What OS?  Any headphones should work with any headphone port...  And if it's those old Apple ones - they should work.

Comment: I can't imagine why they wouldn't work.  Are you sure you had it plugged in all the way?

Comment: @Zoredache yes I plugged it in all the way, no response from my computer and  the sound is still coming from the pc's speakers.

Comment: @nerdwaller I'm on windows 7.

Comment: If it's not detecting them, I would go to your computer manufacturer's site and update/install the drivers for both the chipset and audio (if separate).  Sound's like a possible driver issue.

Comment: @nerdwaller i've added a screenshot of my sound window in case that gives any hints.

Comment: Do you have other headphones you can borrow to try with to be sure it's not them and narrow it to your computer?  By looks of the screenshot, they are not plugged in, and when they are - does that icon become less-grayed out?

Comment: Here's the driver page as well: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/latitude-z600

Comment: @nerdwaller my bad, it is a HP z600 desktop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they should work with your computer. since sometimes you use USB headphones you may need to make sure that your earbuds are set as the primary playback device in the Sound settings. Sound settings can be found in the control panel in category view from the "Hardware and Sound" link and from icon view the "Sound Settings" icon.

Comment: in the sound window, in the playback tab, I just have speakers that seem to be activated, all other icons are blanked out.

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot of the sound window?

Comment: I agree with @nerdwalker it seems like the device is not detecting the earbuds. I would try updating the drivers from the OEM's website and also try using a different pair of headphones or plugging in a pair of speakers to the same port to see if you can get it to recognize a different audio device.